# What is the difference between DEBUG and INFO in Python logging?

Tags: python, debugging, logging

When using the `logging` library, when should I log using `DEBUG`, and when should I use `INFO` instead? All I know is that they are used to show what a program is doing during normal operation.

Comment: You get to decide. It's completely up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up to only show logs of certain level. 
DEBUG and INFO are two levels, info being a more neutral one, used for non-essential stuff and debug being the one that you might use for displaying stuff that might help you debug something.

It is up to you what you use each level for, and what levels you might want to see in your logs. If you disable a level, it will simply not be shown in logs.

Logging has 5 levels, and you can set the levels you need via setLevel() function. See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: Logging has five predefined levels that you are totally free to ignore or supplement as you choose

Answer (score 1):

There are no predetermined roles other than DEBUG being a higher verbosity level than INFO.

Their names imply that INFO is supposed to report on a program's progress while DEBUG is to report info for diagnosing problems.

The key thing to watch for when choosing which level to use for a specific message is to make each level *give a full picture of what is going on,* with the corresponding level of detail. See [How to debug a Python program running as a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51194784/how-to-debug-a-python-program-running-as-a-service/51196240#51196240) for details.

E.g. in one of my programs that utilized a user-provided script to do tasks, I used:

- INFO -- progress on tasks
- VERBOSE (custom level with ID 15) -- info for diagnosing problems in the user script
- DEBUG -- info for diagnosing problems in the program itself

Answer (score 1):

If you view your log messages as part of your application's user interface, INFO messages are for consumption by the administrators or users, whereas debug messages are for consumption by its programmers.  Messages should be designed and emitted with this in mind.